# Using CefSharp Browser to employ Google Meet

Tags: cefsharp

a newbie here. I have installed and have working CefSharp in a VB.Net Application. I am trying to use the ChromiumWebBrowser to use the Google "Meet" web site so I can add meetings to my application. The ChromiumWebBrowser displays the Google Meet Website and asks me to log in. I can input my gmail address but then when  I click Next, I get a Google message saying my browser is not supported. Any ideas?

Comment: Google are no longer allowing logins see https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=16764